# R Heatmap: conditionally change label text colours with (ggplot2 or plotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to produce a **heatmap** with *ggplot2* or *plotly* in R, where the values associated with a block or tile are used as labels in the respective tile. This was not so difficult, but I have removed the legend and would like to change the colours of the labels conditional on their values to increase their visibility.

Here a reproducible examples to show what I mean.

Data (using data.table and dplyr):

```
sig <-  rep(c("sig1", "sig2", "sig3"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.35, 0.25))
date <- c("2019-11-01", "2019-11-02", "2019-11-03")

another <- as.data.table(expand.grid(sig, date))

test_dat_numerics <- another[, number_ok := sample(0:100, 900, replace = TRUE)]
setnames(test_dat_numerics, c("Var1", "Var2"), c("sig", "date"))

test_dat_numerics <- test_dat_numerics[, avg := mean(number_ok), by = .(date, sig)] %>%
  dplyr::select(-number_ok) %>%
  dplyr::rename(number_ok = avg) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(prop = ifelse(number_ok > 50, 1, 0))
  dplyr::distinct()
```

The heatmap (with ggplot2):

```
ggp <- ggplot(test_dat_numerics, aes(date, sig, fill = number_ok)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = test_dat_numerics$number_ok)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

This results in

[image]

The darker a block becomes the less visible the text becomes. To prevent this, my intention is to make the text white when a value is below 50 and black otherwise. This is the part where I failed both with ggplot2 and plotly until now and would be grateful for help.

With plotly:

```
p <- test_dat_numerics %>%
  plot_ly(type = "heatmap",
          x = ~date,
          y = ~sig,
          z = ~number_ok,
          # zmax = 100,
          # zmin = 0,
          showscale = FALSE,
          colorscale = "Blues") %>%
  add_annotations(text = as.character(test_dat_numerics$number_ok),
                  showarrow = FALSE,
                  color = list(if (test_dat_numerics$number_ok[i] > 50) {"black"} else {"white"})) %>%
  layout(title = "Test Heatmap",
         # titlefont = t,
         xaxis = list(title = "Datum"), yaxis = list(title = "Signal")
         )
```

I found a great plotly example [here](https://plot.ly/~cvillamil/4/annotated-heatmap/#code), but I couldn't manage to get to work for my case. Here the annotation part of my code:

```
ann <- list()

    for (i in 1:length(unique(test_dat_numerics$sig))) {
      for (j in 1:length(unique(test_dat_numerics$date))) {
        for (k in 1:(length(unique(test_dat_numerics$sig))*length(unique(test_dat_numerics$date)))) {
          ann[[k]] <- list(
          x = i,
          y = j,
          font = list(color = if (test_dat_numerics$number_ok[i] > 50) {"black"} else {"white"}),
          text = as.character(test_dat_numerics$number_ok[[k]]),
          xref = "x", 
          yref = "y", 
          showarrow = FALSE )
        }
      }
    }

p_test_num_heat <- layout(p, annotations = ann)
```

Here, one of numerous attempts with ggplot2:

```
ggp <- ggplot(test_dat_numerics, aes(date, sig, fill = number_ok)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = test_dat_numerics$number_ok)) +
  geom_label(aes(colour = factor(test_dat_numerics$prop))) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

(This code produces the plot in the image above if the second to last line is removed.)

I'm pretty stuck on this one... Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ggplot2, you can use `colour` in the `aes` of `geom_text` (+ `scale_colour_manual`):

```
ggplot(test_dat_numerics, aes(date, sig, fill = number_ok)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = number_ok, colour =ifelse(number_ok>50, "black", "white"))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("white"="white", "black"="black")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]