# R Plotly Heatmap Conditional Annotation with ifelse?

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

Follwoing:
[R Heatmap: conditionally change label text colours with (ggplot2 or plotly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080936/r-heatmap-conditionally-change-label-text-colours-with-ggplot2-or-plotly)

I thought the code below would create a heatmap whose annotation is white if the value is greater than 5 (so in this case, when (X,Y)=(3,"C")) but it does not work. Any idea?

Thank you!

```
df<-tibble(Y=c("A","B","C"),
           X=c(1,2,3),
           Z=c(1,5,10))
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~X, y=~Y, z=~Z, type='heatmap') %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~Z,
                  showarrow = FALSE,
                  font = list(color = ~ifelse(Z>5,'white','black')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Font colors weren't designed to be dynamic in Plotly. Even though `add_annotations` inherently understands that you want one 'add_annotation' for each value in `Z`, it does *not* assume that's what you mean for the font color. However, you can still have it changed on the fly with a UDF.

This function rebuilds the plot, then parses the annotations to assign colors.

```
that <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)      # build the plot to collect the data
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$layout$annotations), # loop through annotations
      function(j) {
        this <- plt$x$layout$annotations[[j]]             # collect annotation
        colr <- ifelse(this$text > 5, "white", "black")   # test for color
        plt$x$layout$annotations[[j]]$font$color <<- colr # assign color
      })
  plt       # return updated plot
}
```

The way that you use this is by just piping it to the end of your plot call. I didn't tie in exceptions for cases in which no color was specifically assigned. In other words, assign a color in your original plot call, it doesn't matter what color it is.

```
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~X, y = ~Y, z = ~Z, type = 'heatmap') %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~Z,
                  showarrow = FALSE,
                  font = list(color = "black")) %>% that() # <- I'm new!
```

I used the color sequence you chose, but I think this is the opposite of what you really wanted.

[image]

For example, if I swap the conditions for the colors in the function:

```
that <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)      # build the plot to collect the data
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$layout$annotations), # loop through annotations
      function(j) {
        this <- plt$x$layout$annotations[[j]]             # collect annotation
        colr <- ifelse(this$text > 5, "black", "white")   # test for color
        plt$x$layout$annotations[[j]]$font$color <<- colr # assign color
      })
  plt       # return updated plot
}

df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~X, y = ~Y, z = ~Z, type = 'heatmap') %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~Z,
                  showarrow = FALSE,
                  font = list(color = "black")) %>% that()
```

Now you can see the text a lot better:

[image]

By the way, you could also call the plot as it is and use `that(last_plot())` to rerender it with the new text colors.

Both `plotly` and `ggplot2` have the function `last_plot()`; make sure you're calling the `plotly` version if you use this method.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much for the great answer! I cannot upvote as apparently I need to have more presence here but as soon as I can I will.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, you can also use a heatplot like this if you want to show a thresholded map:

```
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Z>5, fill_max = 5)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]